Changing a value in a cell without changing the active sheet
This is a very simple question but I'm not being able to do it in GoogleSheets.
I want to execute an appscript that is able to read and write values in cells in different sheets without activating them.
Imagine that i'm in 'sheet1' and i want to copy A1 from 'sheet2' to B2 in 'sheet3' without activating sheet 2 or 3 - ie i want the screen to remain in the same sheet.
I really don't know how to do this...
I'm around the lines of "getactivesheet" that always change the screen...
I've seen posts using sheets' numbers but i want to use the names and not the numbers...


read and write values in cells in different sheets without activating them

Use Sheet.getRange(), like this:
  const ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  const sheet = ss.getSheetByName('Sheet2');
  const sourceCell = sheet.getRange('A2');
  const targetCell = sheet.getRange('B4');
  const value = sourceCell.getValue();
  targetCell.setValue(value);

See Apps Script at Stack Overflow and Clean Code JavaScript.

Thank you very much. It worked perfectly. I swapped the source and target as it seems more intuitive for me.

See What should I do when someone answers my question?
